# Making a jar file containing SQL commands in Netbeans

Tags: java, sql-server, ms-access, netbeans

I have a program in Netbeans that uses SQL to connect to an Access Database. I am ready to finalize and make a jar file out of the program, but when I 'build and clean' and then try to run the program in command I get:

java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

In my code I access the Database directly using:

```
 Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=C:\\Users\\d9t\\Desktop\\Resource_DB.accdb");
```

Comment: How are you running the program? Are you running it in an IDE or are you running it from the command line?

Comment: When I run it from the IDE the program works as it should, but once I make the jar and attempt to run it in command line I get the above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon this fix http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html

Install UCanAccess-2.0.1-bin.zip and include all the files. I encountered some minor bugs such as not being able to pass ' and " into Access, but it successfully allows 64bit computers to connect 32bit Access.

Hope this helps you Access programmers!

Comment: Thanks for the update. Just to clarify: UCanAccess uses Jackcess to read/write the Access database file (.accdb or .mdb) directly, bypassing any version of the Access Database Engine that might be installed on the machine. So, the computer is not really "connecting to 32-bit (or 64-bit) Access", it is just reading and writing a file.

Answer (score 0):

I have not done this (JDBC-ODBC) for many many years, but I think in addition to what you have done, you also need to add the data source like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca6axakh(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I was under the impression that as long as I am using a DNS-less server, I don't need to setup connection in ODBC. I am able to get it to run in Netbeans without making this connection. I only get this error once I make and run the jar file.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your driver jar may need to be added to the classpath when you are running the program.
Run the program specifying a classpath (-classpath or -cp)

```
java -classpath driver.jar;myprogram.jar my.package.MainClass
```

where my.package.MainClass if the class you want to run

Comment: Running it as: "java -C:\Users\d9t\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Resource Tool\dist driver.jar;Resource_Tool.jar ResourceToolGUI.Resource_Tool_Project.MainClass"                 Does this look right?

Comment: you need java -cp "C:\Users\d9t\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Resource Tool\dist\driver.jar;C:\Users\d9t\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Resource Tool\dist\Resource_Tool.jar" ResourceToolGUI.Resource_Tool_Project.MainClass

Comment: This application is using the JDBC-ODBC Bridge so no other driver is required on the Java side. (The Microsoft Access ODBC Driver needs to be installed in Windows, but that has obviously been done because the application runs correctly from within the IDE.)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to recreate your issue using NetBeans 7.4 and was unsuccessful. My project ran correctly in the NetBeans IDE, and after doing a "Clean and Build" it also ran successfully from the command line via

```
java -jar AccessTest.jar
```

For diagnostic purposes, please try this:

Add the following two lines of code as the very first lines in your `main` method:

```java
System.out.println(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model"));
System.exit(0);
```

Run your code in the IDE and note the number that it prints to the console. (It will either be "32" or "64".)

Then re-build your project and run the `.jar` file from the command line. Does it report the same value when you run it that way?

**Edit re: comment**

The output from the above diagnostics confirmed the problem. The 32-bit version of the Access Database Engine (a.k.a. "ACE") was installed on the machine and the NetBeans configuration was set to run the application in a 32-bit JVM from within NetBeans itself, so that worked fine. However, when the .jar file was run from the command line it was running in a 64-bit JVM so the Access ODBC driver was not available.

The key point here is that the "bitness" of the installed ACE driver will have to match the "bitness" of the JVM under which the Java application is running. That is not really something that you, as the developer, can control. Even if you were to use the `System.getProperty` test to identify the "bitness" under which the application is running, you can't guarantee that the corresponding ACE driver will be installed.

What you *could* do is build your application to use the older 32-bit "Jet" driver...

```
{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}
```

...because that is available on all Windows machines. Your database file would have to use the older `.mdb` file format (because Jet cannot read `.accdb` files) and you could use the `System.getProperty` test to ensure that the application is running under a 32-bit JVM. (That is, if the call returned "64" just tell the user that they must run the application under a 32-bit JVM and then exit.)

Comment: You were right, I had to switch my IDE to 32bit in order to connect Java and Access. The jar is running 32bit but Command is running a 64bit environment. I will have to export this to another 64bit computer in the future. Is there anyway I can keep the file as 32bit so that it works with Access and run it in a 64bit environment?

Comment: Gord Thompson thank you, you have been an enormous help. Just to clarify, there is no way to connect 32bit Access and Java and then run it on a 64bit JVM. If I wanted to be able to run this database connection I would have to check each machine for it's JVM version and install 32bit if it didn't already exist.

Comment: @Crash re: "Just to clarify, there is no way to connect 32bit Access and Java and then run it on a 64bit JVM." - That is correct. If the application is running under a 64-bit JVM then it cannot use a 32-bit ODBC driver.