# Connecting to Microsoft Access Database from Runnable JAR file

Tags: java, eclipse, ms-access, jar, executable-jar

When I use eclipse to create a runnable JAR file, it opens, however, it does not connect to the database. When I use eclipse to to run the said file and, there is no problem.

**NOTE** *Db is a System Data Source that connects to the Microsoft Access Database*

**The specific error is**

```
java.sql.SQLException:[Microsoft][OBDC Driver Manager] The specific DSN contains an architechture mismatch between the Driver Application
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Code to connect to database is below.

```
private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
        try{

        String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
        Class.forName(driver);
        String login = "jdbc:odbc:Db";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(login);
        System.out.print("Connected");
    }catch (Exception ex){}

}
```

Comment: Fix your `catch` block to display what the error is (something like `ex.printStackTrace(System.out);` might suffice), and then edit your question to tell *us* what it says.

Comment: Have your application display `System.out.println(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model"));`. Does it show the same value when you run the executable JAR file as it does when you run the application in Eclipse?

Comment: The application runs perfectly in eclipse and Netbeans... it is after it has been exported, it runs, but it does not connect to the database.

Comment: That's probably because when you run the application under Eclipse or Netbeans it is running under a different JVM than when you run the executable JAR. Specifically, in one case it is running under a 64-bit JVM and in the other case it is running under a 32-bit JVM. That's what I was trying to illustrate with my previous comment. For an answer to a similar question look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21291670/2144390).